# Which class is responsible for scanning @Entity annotation in Spring JPA, Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa

I'm looking for a Class which is responsible for Scanning all classes annotated with **@Entity** in JPA, Hibernate, or Spring.

I want to extend that class and add some logic while scanning the class.

I have searched everywhere( spring docs, JPA, Hibernate docs) but could not find it.

Comment: I think SessionFactoryImpl.java is responsible for scanning @Entity in Hibernate. See the github link. https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/internal/SessionFactoryImpl.java

Answer (score 1):

As soon as Spring boot detects you need that, the auto configuration of the JPA repositories is enabled.
From the `@JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` specification (emphasis is mine) :

> Auto-configuration for Spring Data's JPA Repositories. **Activates when
>   there is a bean of type DataSource configured in the context, the
>   Spring Data JPA JpaRepository type is on the classpath, and there is
>   no other, existing JpaRepository configured**. Once in effect, the
>   auto-configuration is the equivalent of enabling JPA repositories
>   using the EnableJpaRepositories annotation. This configuration class
>   will activate after the Hibernate auto-configuration.

To override that, add explicitly the `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation but you could not add any logic in but fields defined in the annotation.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I want to know the class who is responsible for scanning all my classes which are annotated with @Entity.

Answer (score 1):

Can't help you with the native class, which is responsible for scanning, but can tell you how to scan in your own class. The code is borrowed from my project - it enables exposing of id for each entity. You don't have to add new into the list each time - it's easy to forget this step.
You need to have a configuration extending RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter or RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration and to add a method as follows:

```
@Override
public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {

    // getting a list of all classes annotated with @Entity
    List<Class<?>> classes = CPScanner.scanClasses(new PackageNameFilter("ru.outofrange.*"),
            new ClassFilter().appendAnnotation(Entity.class));
    Class[] arrayClasses = new Class[classes.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++) {
        arrayClasses[i] = classes.get(i);
    }

    config.exposeIdsFor(arrayClasses);
}
```

This dependency is required:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.corn</groupId>
    <artifactId>corn-cps</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a very broad question but you need to look at the [source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework) to understand that.

Comment: Thanks for the source code. I know it can be either from spring or hibernate source code